# Pytorch: how will next() behave for a list of DataLoaders of different length

Tags: python, pytorch, iterator, pytorch-dataloader

My data has several conditions A, B, C. I would like to do the following.

- Draw a sample for each condition
- Draw a random sample from the full data set
- Some training magic

Thus, I would have in one batch something like

```
[condition_A, condition_B, condition_C, random_sample]
```

I have created a dictionary of the form

```
loader_dict = {
cond_A : DataLoader(...Subset Magic...), 
cond_B : DataLoader(...Subset Magic...),
cond_C : DataLoader(...Subset Magic...)
}

train_loader = DataLoader(...full dataset...)
```

Now during each epoch I would like to

1. Get a batch from each of the 4 loaders
2. Process them in some net shenanigans

Currently, I am a bit stuck on the 1st point.

My approach so far is

```
# get a list of form [loader_A, loader_B, loader_C]
train_loaders = list(zip(*loader_dict.values()))

for batch_idx, batch in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader)):
    condit_sample = [next(loader) for loader in train_loaders]
    
    # do something with torch.cat([batch, condit_sample])
```

Now I am not sure - will the `next()` call actually always just pick the first batch of the conditions loaders (**not desired**) or will it actually iterate through the samples of the conditions?

Also, my data has something like `50% condition_A, 35% condition_B, 15% condition_C`

Thus, I wonder, whether my code would run e.g. through all 100 batches of the full dataset and repeat condition_A twice, condition_B nearly 3 times and condition_C 6 times? Or will the code just run through all samples of condition C and break down?

Currently, the multiple cycling through the conditional samples would suffice.

For later purposes, I would like to consider the following:

- just pick a really random sample (in each epoch something different) from the full dataset
- cycle through all the conditional loader samples
- terminate the epoch whenever the smallest condition sample is "cycled through"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the experiment myself. It will behave as `itertools.cycle()`